# Unable to read output from barcode scanner

Tags: android

I want to upload the result from the barcode scanner to the edit text, but it is not displaying in the edit text. May I know what the problem is and how do I solve it?

This is my code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
private EditText ScanBarcode;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);

    ScanBarcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editscanbar);
}

public void scanCode(View view){
    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    scannerView.setResultHandler(new ZXingScannerResultHandler());

    setContentView(scannerView);
    scannerView.startCamera();
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    scannerView.stopCamera();
}

class ZXingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
            @Override
            public void handleResult(Result result){
                String resultCode = result.getText().toString();
                ScanBarcode.setText(resultCode);
                Toast.makeText(ScannerActivity.this, resultCode, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
                scannerView.stopCamera();

    }
}
}
```

I've changed it and there is still nothing showing up in the edit text

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
private EditText ScanBarcode;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle State) {
    super.onCreate(State);
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);

    ScanBarcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editscanbar);
}

public void scanCode(View view){
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);

    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}
@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult){
    ScanBarcode.setText(rawResult.getText());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the ResultHandler in your Activity, override the callback method and there set the result of the scan in your EditText, example:

```
public class SimpleScannerActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
private EditText editText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
    setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
    mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    // Do something with the result here
    editText.setText(rawResult.getText());
    Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
    Log.v(TAG, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)

    // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
}
```

Hope it helps!